# Manage queues for Websphere Liberty

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-mq, websphere-liberty

Is there any ability to list/manage WAS Liberty queues besides server xml config? Liberty version does not support WAS admin console with it's MQ managing functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebSphere Liberty was designed to have simple configuration, that can be part of your source artifacts and deployed easily via CI/CD tools. So in general it is rather not recommended to modify running server configuration, rather prepare and deliver new server via your pipeline.

Having said that, you can modify `server.xml` file, and most of the modification will be integrated into running server without the restart.

You also have `adminCenter` feature, which will give you simplified web console. That console will allow you to modify `server.xml` via browser, with editor that knows the correct syntax so you dont have to remember all the tag names. However you will not get 'wizard' like console, that you currently have in traditional WAS server.